# Xamarin.iOS - Problem trying to get NSData from NSItemProvider with LoadDataRepresentation

Tags: ios, xamarin, share-extension

I'm trying to develop a Share Extension to take a file (image, pdf, office, text, etc) and send it to cloud through an Rest API but cannot convert data in NSItemProvider to NSData. Same time I'm having issues to debug the Share Extension project with VS2017, so I'm doing old school using flags and an alert instead.
The code of my ViewController is this

```
using CoreFoundation;
using Foundation;
using Social;
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace Share
{
    public partial class ShareExtensionViewController : SLComposeServiceViewController
    {
        public string message = string.Empty;

        public ShareExtensionViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
        }

        public override bool IsContentValid()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void DidSelectPost()
        {
            NSItemProvider itemProvider = new NSItemProvider();
            try
            {
                NSExtensionItem item = ExtensionContext.InputItems[0];

                if (item != null)
                {
                    message = "NSExtensionItem 1\n";

                    itemProvider = item.Attachments[0];
                    if (itemProvider?.HasItemConformingTo(itemProvider.RegisteredTypeIdentifiers[0]) == true)
                    {
                        message += "NSItemProvider 2\n";

                        itemProvider.LoadDataRepresentation(itemProvider.RegisteredTypeIdentifiers[0], (dataRaw, error) =>
                        {
                            var data = dataRaw;
                            DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchSync(() =>
                            {
                                message += "NSData 3\n" + error;

                                if (data != null)
                                {
                                    message += "dataBytes 4\n";
                                    //byte[] dataBytes = data.ToArray();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message += "\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace;
            }

            message += "\n" + ExtensionContext.InputItems[0].AttributedContentText;

            UIAlertController alert = UIAlertController.Create(itemProvider.RegisteredTypeIdentifiers[0], message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

            PresentViewController(alert, true, () =>
            {
                DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAfter(new DispatchTime(DispatchTime.Now, 5000000000), () =>
                {
                    ExtensionContext.CompleteRequest(null, null);
                });
            });
        }

        public override SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem[] GetConfigurationItems()
        {
            return new SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem[0];
        }
    }
}
```

The execution is simply passing by of LoadDataRepresentation method. I tried with LoadItem with same result.

Please, need some help with this.

Comment: As far as the issue of debugging the share extension, there is a known issue where this won't work if using the remoted iOS simulator on Windows. See: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/297510/shareviewcontroller-code-not-running-when-using-io.html . Try turning off that feature in Tools > Options > Xamarin > iOS Settings and use the simulator directly on the Mac build host.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`LoadDataRepresentation` method(s) of NSItemProvider?](http://LoadDataRepresentation)

There are three overloads:

```
LoadDataRepresentation(String, Action<NSData, NSError>) : NSProgress
LoadDataRepresentationAsync(String) : System.Threading.Tasks.Task<NSData>
LoadDataRepresentationAsync(String, out NSProgress) : System.Threading.Tasks.Task<NSData>
```

The second seems to be the simplest, just call it with `await` and you should get back an NSData object.

EDIT: Oops, I see you are using the first overload of the above. Are you sure that `dataRaw` is a valid `NSData` object? You don't seem to be checking if `error` is null or not, could there be an error you are missing?